# Black Hills Spruce Leader Drooping and Brown

Tags: trees

[image][image][image]I have a black hills spruce tree, about 8 feet tall. It was planted a year and a half ago. The leader has new growth at the top, but parts of it are drooping and browning (to about 1 foot down from the top). The rest of the tree looks healthy, no browning. Should I prune the leader?

UPDATE - I pruned the leader. Should I spray for insects? If so, any recommendations on when and what to spray?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome! A picture of the tree would be appropriate.

Comment: Possibly borer damage ; they attack the leaders of other trees like some pines. If so, the leader is dead. A borer will hollow out the leader and may leave some evidence on the outside like sap or wood shavings.

Comment: Looks like there's a second leader developing to the left in the picture - I'd give it a bit longer to see what happens, but you may well need to prune back the original leader - it looks like branches coming off it lower down are starting to droop too, so if that gets worse, cut it out below the point where drooping is apparent. Question is, why has this happened... inspect the tree thoroughly for signs of infestation or infection (although as you say, the rest of it looks perfectly healthy). Check the base of the tree too for soft areas or signs of rotting

Comment: Looks like sap has come out of borer hole and dried.